# Print RTF file to default printer on client side using Jquery or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am creating an `.rtf` file based on user submitted form for php web application. Until here it's fine.

Now I need to print this `.rtf` file on client side default printer silently without any `rtf` tags in it(print rtf file directly as it is as we have, when we open `.rtf` in MS-Word).

So is there any script, using javascript or jQuery to do this? Showing the printer dialog also works for me.

Can anyone please suggest me with examples. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would require your script to reach outside of the browser sandbox and script the application to initiate printing, so it can not be done just using javascript and jQuery.

There are few approaches that might work:

First, if you converted the RTF to HTML unsing `unoconv`, and then called print via javascript, that would allow you to print from the browser, but it would probably include the browser's default headers and footers.

Second, but only for an Intranet application, you could lower the security settings for ActiveX from the Intranet zone, and run Word as an ActiveX control:

```
var msw = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
```

Third, again for an Intranet, have the server run OpenOffice and print to the network printer nearest the user.

Consider the use case and whether automatic printing adds enough value for the end users to be worth the extra hassle. Most of the things I "print" from the web, I actually just print to PDF and archive to disk, and most print dialog boxes require a few extra mouse clicks before sending the job to the printer anyway.